# Строки в Java и разные конструкции

Tags: java, строки

**Чем отличается вот такая конструкция:**

```
String name = "Tom";
```

**от такой:**

```
String name = new String("Jerry");
```

Не очень еще понимаю что такое ссылка.  
**Зачем делать вот так?**

```
public void foo(){
   new String("Моя строка");
}
```

Если можно сделать вот так:

```
public void foo(){
  String name = "Mike";
}
```

Или же

```
public void foo(){
      String name = new String("John");
    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`String name = "Tom"` в первый раз создаёт в памяти строковый литерал.
Последующее использование того же литерала вызовет создание новой ссылки на то же место.
`String cat = "Tom"` будет использовать ту же строку, адреса одинаковые.

`String name = new String("Jerry");` создаёт новый объект в памяти.
Если сделать
`String mouse = new String("Jerry");`  - создаётся ещё один объект в памяти. Адреса разные, т.е. строка "Jerry" дважды хранится.

Есть ещё тонкость. Сравнение с помощью "=="  проверяет идентичность адресов, а метод `String.equals` выполняет сравнение содержимого. Поэтому `name==mouse` вернёт false - адреса-то разные.

Этот пример:

```
public void foo(){
   new String("Моя строка");
}
```

не имеет большого смысла. Ссылку на новый объект же надо куда-то назначить. В языках без сбора мусора такой код приведёт к утечке памяти, в Java висячий объект должен быть утилизирован. Для остальных примеров описанное остаётся в силе.

> Не очень еще понимаю что такое ссылка.

У тебя в телефоне записан "Колян" и его номер.
У его мамы записан "сынок" и его номер.
У начальника в телефоне записан "сисадмин" и его номер.
У подруги записан "ушастый зая" и его номер.
Колян один, а ссылок на него может быть несколько.

Колян уволился, начальник нанял нового сисадмина. 
Ссылка в его телефоне стала невалидной (в Java сборщик может за этим следить, но в данном контексте неактуально).
Он нанял нового `sysadm  = ("Петин номер");` и его ссылка теперь указывает на новый объект.
А твоя не изменилась, он по-прежнему Колян.

Comment: Я добавил немного информации, можете ответ расширить, заранее спасибо!

Comment: Я бы еще добавил бы про сравнение срок через == будут сравниват ссылки и что для "Tom" будет true как и для equals, а вот для  "Jerry" равенство будет только по equals.

Comment: @Ihar Hulevich Да, ещё не дошёл до этого

Comment: @MBo, пример с "Коляном" прикольный!)

Answer (score 2):

Объекты `String` в основном представляют собой обертки вокруг строковых литералов. Уникальные строковые объекты объединяются, чтобы предотвратить ненужное создание объектов, и `JVM` может решить объединить строковые литералы изнутри. Существует также прямая поддержка байт-кода для `String`-констант, на которые ссылаются несколько раз, предоставляя компилятору поддержку этого.

Последние два примера - это переменные, которые хранят ссылки на объект. В 3-м примере вы просто создаете объект, без ссылки. Поэтому у вас не будет к нему доступа и он скорее всего удалится сборщиком мусора.

Соответствующий отрывок из [JLS 7 3.10.5](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-3.html#jls-3.10.5):

> Кроме того, строковый литерал всегда ссылается на тот же экземпляр
>   класса String. Это связано с тем, что строковые литералы, или, в более
>   общем смысле, строки, которые являются значениями константных
>   выражений (§15.28), "интернированы", чтобы обмениваться уникальными
>   экземплярами, используя метод String.intern.

Пример:

```
        String hello = "Hello", lo = "lo";
        System.out.print((hello == "Hello") + " ");
        System.out.print((Other.hello == hello) + " ");
        System.out.print((other.Other.hello == hello) + " ");
        System.out.print((hello == ("Hel"+"lo")) + " ");
        System.out.print((hello == ("Hel"+lo)) + " ");
        System.out.println(hello == ("Hel"+lo).intern());
```

Выведет `true true true true false true`.

> Язык программирования Java требует, чтобы идентичные строковые
>   литералы (то есть литералы, содержащие одну и ту же последовательность
>   кодовых точек) должны относиться к одному экземпляру класса `String`
>   (JLS §3.10.5). Кроме того, если метод `String.intern` вызывается в любой
>   строке, результатом является ссылка на тот же экземпляр класса,
>   который будет возвращен, если эта строка появилась как литерал. Таким
>   образом, следующее выражение должно иметь значение `true`: `("a" + "b" + "c").intern() == "abc"`.

Взято [отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2486191/what-is-the-java-string-pool-and-how-is-s-different-from-new-strings).